# Could not access file PHPMailer in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer

I am creating a project using Laravel. I want to send an email with an attachment; however, this is not working. I know there are many questions regarding this, but unfortunately, I could not find the answer.

```php
$file1 = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$path = base_path();
$path .= '/public/uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path);

DB::statement("UPDATE orders SET pdf = '".$fileData."' WHERE id = '".$id."'");

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer(); // create a n
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';
$mail->SetFrom('xxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxx.com');
$mail->Subject = 'xxxxx Ready';
$mail->Body = $text;
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxx.com");
$mail->AddAttachment($pdfLink, $fileData, $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
$mail->Send();
```

The generated PDF link is accessible, and when I open the PDF link in a new tab, it works. However, I don't know why **PHPMailer told me that I could not access**.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, i am just getting the file from server. This is the reason this is not working.The file should upload from actual path.

Answer (score 0):

login to your gmail account, go to [Enable access](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=ENTER_YOUR_GMAIL_USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=ENTER_YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

and all must be working fine )